# Stylesheet Setting not to display <li> contents in new line on IE and Firefox

Tags: css, list, firefox, google-chrome, newline

On the web page which I am coding, I found difference in displaying list between Chrome and (IE and Firefox).

I suppose my style sheet is wrong. But where?
Why the contents of "li" are set to new line on IE and Firefox?
I want display like Chrome

On My Stylesheet:

```
    a {
    color: #F60;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:hover{
    color: #F60;
    text-decoration: underline
    }

    li {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    }
```

The Result is as this image:

[image]

I tried

```
    ul{
    display: inline
    }
```

but, it removed marker on the head.

Comment: do you try with display:inline but in the "li" tags?

Comment: Can you supply the HTML and CSS please? Or even a link to the site you are working on?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about which browser versions you're using, specifically for FF? I find it hard to believe that FF would style `li` elements differently from Chrome (for IE it isn't so hard to believe). It may also be due to the styling of elements other than those you list. It might help us (and potentially yourself) if you can strip your problem down to only its essential components and post it, perhaps on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36854), but it implies that your `<a>` are block elements.
By the way, don't need to redefine same color in `:hover`.